# Error converting JSON string to Python dict using repr()

Tags: python, json

I have a sticky problem procesing the JSON string below. My goal is to convert the JSON string into a Python dict.
When I prefix my string with r, I can successfully convert the JSON string to a python dict. Since this strings comes from an API request, I require a different solution.
I have tried using repr() function (recommended) solution, but it doesn't work.

**Not working but ideal**

```
import json

s = '{"success":true,"dashboard":{"id":347,"name":"Revenue","layout_id":0,"layout":"{\"l\":[{\"dimensions\":{\"w\":4,\"h\":5,\"x\":0,\"y\":0,\"i\":\"0\",\"minW\":3,\"minH\":5,\"moved\":false,\"static\":false},\"widget\":{\"id\":9853,\"type\":\"chart\",\"report\":{\"id\":1407}}},{\"dimensions\":{\"w\":4,\"h\":10,\"x\":4,\"y\":0,\"i\":\"1\",\"minW\":3,\"minH\":5,\"moved\":false,\"static\":false},\"widget\":{\"id\":1935,\"type\":\"chart\",\"report\":{\"id\":1408}}},{\"dimensions\":{\"w\":4,\"h\":10,\"x\":8,\"y\":20,\"i\":\"2\",\"minW\":3,\"minH\":5,\"moved\":false,\"static\":false},\"widget\":{\"id\":2717,\"type\":\"chart\",\"report\":{\"id\":1409}}},{\"dimensions\":{\"w\":4,\"h\":10,\"x\":0,\"y\":5,\"i\":\"3\",\"minW\":3,\"minH\":5,\"moved\":false,\"static\":false},\"widget\":{\"id\":9831,\"type\":\"chart\",\"report\":{\"id\":1406}}},{\"dimensions\":{\"w\":3,\"h\":5,\"x\":8,\"y\":0,\"i\":\"4\",\"minW\":3,\"minH\":5,\"moved\":false,\"static\":false},\"widget\":{\"id\":3578,\"type\":\"summary\",\"report\":{\"id\":1414}}},{\"dimensions\":{\"w\":4,\"h\":10,\"x\":6,\"y\":10,\"i\":\"5\",\"minW\":3,\"minH\":5,\"moved\":false,\"static\":false},\"widget\":{\"id\":3125,\"type\":\"chart\",\"report\":{\"id\":1408}}}]}","defaultdash":0,"permission_id":1,"description":null,"created_by":2,"group_id":null,"field1":null,"fieldtype1":null,"field2":null,"fieldtype2":null,"field3":null,"fieldtype3":null,"field4":null,"fieldtype4":null,"field5":null,"fieldtype5":null,"field6":null,"fieldtype6":null,"field7":null,"fieldtype7":null,"field8":null,"fieldtype8":null,"field9":null,"fieldtype9":null,"field10":null,"fieldtype10":null,"field11":null,"fieldtype11":null,"field12":null,"fieldtype12":null,"field13":null,"fieldtype13":null,"field14":null,"fieldtype14":null,"field15":null,"fieldtype15":null,"field16":null,"fieldtype16":null,"field17":null,"fieldtype17":null,"field18":null,"fieldtype18":null,"created_at":"2022-12-05 09:43:09","updated_at":"2023-02-08 08:52:27","deleted_at":null}}'

s1 = repr(s)[1:-1]
s2 = json.loads(s1)
print(type(s2))
```

**Working but not ideal**

import json

```
s = r'{"success":true,"dashboard":{"id":347,"name":"Revenue","layout_id":0,"layout":"{\"l\":[{\"dimensions\":{\"w\":4,\"h\":5,\"x\":0,\"y\":0,\"i\":\"0\",\"minW\":3,\"minH\":5,\"moved\":false,\"static\":false},\"widget\":{\"id\":9853,\"type\":\"chart\",\"report\":{\"id\":1407}}},{\"dimensions\":{\"w\":4,\"h\":10,\"x\":4,\"y\":0,\"i\":\"1\",\"minW\":3,\"minH\":5,\"moved\":false,\"static\":false},\"widget\":{\"id\":1935,\"type\":\"chart\",\"report\":{\"id\":1408}}},{\"dimensions\":{\"w\":4,\"h\":10,\"x\":8,\"y\":20,\"i\":\"2\",\"minW\":3,\"minH\":5,\"moved\":false,\"static\":false},\"widget\":{\"id\":2717,\"type\":\"chart\",\"report\":{\"id\":1409}}},{\"dimensions\":{\"w\":4,\"h\":10,\"x\":0,\"y\":5,\"i\":\"3\",\"minW\":3,\"minH\":5,\"moved\":false,\"static\":false},\"widget\":{\"id\":9831,\"type\":\"chart\",\"report\":{\"id\":1406}}},{\"dimensions\":{\"w\":3,\"h\":5,\"x\":8,\"y\":0,\"i\":\"4\",\"minW\":3,\"minH\":5,\"moved\":false,\"static\":false},\"widget\":{\"id\":3578,\"type\":\"summary\",\"report\":{\"id\":1414}}},{\"dimensions\":{\"w\":4,\"h\":10,\"x\":6,\"y\":10,\"i\":\"5\",\"minW\":3,\"minH\":5,\"moved\":false,\"static\":false},\"widget\":{\"id\":3125,\"type\":\"chart\",\"report\":{\"id\":1408}}}]}","defaultdash":0,"permission_id":1,"description":null,"created_by":2,"group_id":null,"field1":null,"fieldtype1":null,"field2":null,"fieldtype2":null,"field3":null,"fieldtype3":null,"field4":null,"fieldtype4":null,"field5":null,"fieldtype5":null,"field6":null,"fieldtype6":null,"field7":null,"fieldtype7":null,"field8":null,"fieldtype8":null,"field9":null,"fieldtype9":null,"field10":null,"fieldtype10":null,"field11":null,"fieldtype11":null,"field12":null,"fieldtype12":null,"field13":null,"fieldtype13":null,"field14":null,"fieldtype14":null,"field15":null,"fieldtype15":null,"field16":null,"fieldtype16":null,"field17":null,"fieldtype17":null,"field18":null,"fieldtype18":null,"created_at":"2022-12-05 09:43:09","updated_at":"2023-02-08 08:52:27","deleted_at":null}}'

s1 = json.loads(s)
print(type(s1))
```

Comment: If your string is coming from an API request, it should effectively be as if it already had an `r` prefix - backslash escapes aren't processed. You don't need to (and can't) "un-process" the backslashes.

Comment: `repr` should not be involved at any point in the process. Simply calling `json.loads` on the text of the API response should be sufficient. If that does not work, you're going to have to show both the code you're using and the output of `print`-ing the JSON text you get from the API for us to be able to debug the problem.